Angular 14 title theming
How i can set theme color for mat-dialog-title.
I tried this
<h2 mat-dialog-title color="primary">Title</h2>

But it doesn't work.
At the same time  the code
<button mat-button-icon color="primary">

works!

You need to use custom CSS. mat-dialog-title doesn't have a color input. See the docs.
